# How correct the invalid range error while downloading S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When my users are downloading a PDF file (150 KB), they get this error sometimes:

> errorCode: InvalidRange

> errorMessage: The requested range is not satisfiable

The userAgent string looks like this:

```
[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; en-in; Redmi 5 Build/OPM1.171019.026) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/12.4.3-g]
```

The error can not be reproduced because some users with the same userAgent are able to download the file without any problem.
Is there anything I can do to find the exact reason of this error?

Comment: Can you show us the code that is doing the download?

Comment: sorry, due to company security policy this is the only information I have.

Comment: You could [Log requests using server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) to hope to gain more information. It will show the individual requests sent to S3.